# Split delimited string and remove escape sequences

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to split a comma separated string, which contents are sometimes between quotes. An example could be:

> 1,"TEST",22345,"18,95", Ab"cde

The first problem here is to split the string only when the comma is not surrounded by quotes like "18,95". I've done that with a simple Regex. The next problem is to cut out the quotes, where they surround the content. For "TEST" and "18,95" the quotes should be removed.The quote in Ab"cde should be left untouched. Here is my code so far:

```
List<string> results = Regex.Matches(this.Content, @"[\""](.+?)[\""]|[^,]+")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(m => m.Value)
                            .Select(s => s.StartsWith("\"") && s.EndsWith("\"") ? s.Remove(1,1).Remove(s.Length-1,1) : s)
                            .ToList();
```

For the second `Select` I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` since the second `Remove` doesn't work with `s` anymore. I thought it should work, but somehow doesn't.

If there is a better way to do this I would be happy to learn about it.

Comment: Did you try a CSV parser?

Comment: Hint: string is Immutable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to implement one

Comment: You do not need to implement one, it is already present in C#. The answer you accepted will fail on escaped quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you absolutely win this! TextFieldParser from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` is the way to go! If you post an answer I will select it as correct. Thank you

Comment: I will close as a dupe then once  I find the relevant post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the value between quotes and the unquoted value in named capture groups with the same name and retrieve the matched capture with `Match.Groups["group_name"]`:

```
List<string> results = Regex.Matches(this.Content, @"[\""](?<value>.+?)[\""]|(?<value>[^,]+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["value"].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M8lJDR

To take into account potential empty values change `+` to `*` and surround the regex with `(?<=^|,)` and `(?=,|$)`:

```
List<string> results = Regex.Matches(input,
        @"(?<=^|,)(?:""(?<value>.*?)""|(?<value>[^,]*))(?=,|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["value"].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WqRD20

Comment: Wow. that is a good one! Perfect. Do you perhaps also have an idea how I could adjust the regex to also capture empty 'values'. Like in 1,2,,4 there would be an empty third place, which should result in an empty string

Comment: Just change quantifiers from `+` to `*`. See the updated demo

Comment: I thought of that too, but unfortunately it adds an empty result after every 'normal' result which I would need to cleanup

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: yeah, an extra delimiter check is required. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `s.Remove(1,1)`, the resulting string will be shorter than `s` (which remains unchanged)!

Use

```
s.Remove(1,1).Remove(s.Length-2,1)
```

or

```
s.Remove(s.Length-1,1).Remove(1,1)
```

instead of

```
s.Remove(1,1).Remove(s.Length-1,1)
```

This will still fail, when `s="\""`. To cover this, you have to update the condition:

```
s.StartsWith("\"") && s.EndsWith("\"") && s.Length > 1 ? s.Remove(s.Length-1,1).Remove(1,1) : s
```

Comment: I've allready tried that. doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.Substring()`:

```
List<string> results = Regex.Matches(content, @"[\""](.+?)[\""]|[^,]+")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(m => m.Value)
                        .Select(s => s.StartsWith("\"") && s.EndsWith("\"") 
                            ? s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2) : s)
                        .ToList();
```

Output:

```
1
TEST
22345
18,95
Ab"cde
```

**Note:** Doesn't work properly for parts that contain more than 2 quotes i.e `""test""work"",1`

Comment: But that is exactly, what I don't want since the quotes are still in the result

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Guess I missed that. Updated the answer to use `.Substring()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could loop through each of `results` and:

```
for (int i=0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
   if (results[i].StartsWith("\"")) 
       results[i] = results[i].Remove(0, 1);

   if (results[i].EndsWith("\""))  
      results[i] = results[i].Remove(results[i].Length - 1, 1);
}
```